# PostGIS - Get geofence polygon points within 100 metres of an existing geofence

Tags: formula, polygon, postgis, latitude-longitude

Let's say I have a geofence polygon with the following coordinates

```
POLYGON((-36.861986 174.726745,-36.859241 174.730442,-36.859821 174.730976,-36.862321 174.728156,-36.861986 174.726745))
```

I'd like to be able to generate another set of polygon points from this that is within a 100 metre radius. Is there any formula to achieve this?

My use case is that if I have an existing geofence polygon, I want to create another geofence polygon surrounding it in a distance of 100 metres.

I'm using the following query to insert data into my table. The columns 'geofence' and 'geofence_buffer' are of type geography. The column with the name 'geography' is of type text. I just use that for a quick reference.

```
insert into site(name,status,client_id,geofence_type,geography_drawn,geofence,geofence_buffer)
values('Fanshawe','Active',1,1,'POLYGON((-36.849530 174.760984,-36.839295 174.763729,-36.841696 174.779093,-36.854061 174.774291,-36.849530 174.760984))',
      'SRID=4267;POLYGON((-36.849530 174.760984,-36.839295 174.763729,-36.841696 174.779093,-36.854061 174.774291,-36.849530 174.760984))',
      (select ST_Buffer(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4267;POLYGON((-36.849530 174.760984,-36.839295 174.763729,-36.841696 174.779093,-36.854061 174.774291,-36.849530 174.760984))'),100)));
```

Data gets inserted just fine but when I run the following query to find if a point exists within a geofence_buffer, I get the error below.

```
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
LINE 1: ...ect * from site where ST_DWithin(geofence_buffer, 'SRID=4267...
                                                             ^
ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
SQL state: XX000
```

The query I use is

```
select * from site where ST_DWithin(geofence_buffer, 'SRID=4267;POINT(-36.848362 174.764417)',0.0,false);
```

However, if I query within a geofence like this, then everything works fine.

```
select * from site where ST_DWithin(geofence, 'SRID=4267;POINT(-36.848362 174.764417)',0.0,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the coordinates must be expressed as longitude first, then latitude. You would need to swap the coordinates in your input

```
POLYGON(( 174.726745 -36.861986, 174.730442 -36.859241, 174.730976 -36.859821, 174.728156 -36.862321, 174.726745 -36.861986))
```

Then you can use [`ST_BUFFER`](https://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) to create a buffer around your polygon. To specify a distance in meters while having coordinates in lat/long, it is easiest to cast `geometry` to `geography`

```sql
with src as (select st_geomFromText('POLYGON(( 174.726745 -36.861986, 174.730442 -36.859241, 174.730976 -36.859821, 174.728156 -36.862321, 174.726745 -36.861986))') geom)
select st_buffer(geom::geography,100)::geometry 
from src;
```

Since your data is not in 4326 but in 4267, and that `st_buffer` returns geographies in 4326, you would have to reproject:

```
with src as (select st_geomFromText('POLYGON(( 174.726745 -36.861986, 174.730442 -36.859241, 174.730976 -36.859821, 174.728156 -36.862321, 174.726745 -36.861986))') geom)
select ST_Transform(st_buffer(geom::geography,100)::geometry,4267) 
from src;
```

Comment: Thanks JGH. I've updated my question with quite a bit of more detail. Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @user1066568 see edit. You would need to reproject the buffer